# How to communicate between JavaScript and native iOS with outusing PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am new hybrid application mobile developer. I want to know one thing, how is the communication between iOS native code and JavaScript done without using PhoneGap?

Is there any way to communicate between iOS native and JavaScript with out using PhoneGap and JavaScript to native iOS?

Can please any one help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you [call Objective C from Javascript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html) and to call Javascript Function from Objective C just invoke the webview control and call the function just like you call a URL page and will execute the function.

Let me know if it helped you!